# I can't get my page to change after I hit the enter key

Tags: html, css, forms, input, submit

I have been working on a website, but for some reason when I click enter it stays on the same page. But when I click the button I added on the page itself it works. What I'm trying to do is go from my login page, index.html, to my home page after the password is verified, home.html. Any Ideas?

````````````````````````````````````````````
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/popup.css?Version=1.1">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="box">
            <form id="myform-search" method="post" autocomplete="off">
            <h1>Enter Password</h1>
              <p>
                <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter Password" id="p" class="password">
                <button class="unmask" type="button" onclick="toggle()"></button>
                <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="done()">Enter</button>
              </p>
            </form>

          </div>
          <div id="wrong">
            <p>Sorry, but the password you entered is incorrect!</p>
        </div>

            <!--Javascript to show password Box-->
            <script>

                //Verifies password
                function done() { 
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
    var password = document.getElementById("p").value;
    if (password == "12345") {
       location.replace("http://apr.great-site.net/Home/home.html");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").style.display = "block";
    }

};

function toggle() {
  var x = document.getElementById("p");
  if (x.type === "password") {
    x.type = "text";
  } else {
    x.type = "password";
  }
}
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```````````````````````````````````````````
````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Try replacing `type="button"` with `type="submit"` on your submit `<button>`

Comment: do you realize that you are not even submitting the form? You are doing a redirection...also you have a duplicate <form> tag, this is bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 // Verifies password
 function done() { 
    document.getElementById("box").style.display = "none";
    var password = document.getElementById("p").value;
    if (password == "12345") {
       // returning true will submit the form
       return true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("wrong").style.display = "block";
        // returning false will prevent submiting the form
        return false;
    }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/popup.css?Version=1.1">
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div id="box">
            <form id="myform-search" method="post" action="validationUrlHere" autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return done();">
            <h1>Enter Password</h1>
              <p>
                <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter Password" id="p" class="password">
                <!-- Commented this button as it is not needed in the context of the solution -->
                <!--<button class="unmask" type="button" onclick="toggle()">something</button>-->

                <!-- HERE is the interesting part : -->

                <!-- Clicking the "Enter" button has same effect as -->
                <!-- hitting the default submit button or pressing the Enter button on your -->
                <!-- keyboard. Your cursor focus must be inside one of the form's elements, -->
                <!-- preferably in the password input field -->
                <button class="enter" type="button" onclick="done()">Enter</button>
                <input type="submit" value="Real Submit" />
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
          
          <div id="wrong" style="display: none;">
            <p>Sorry, but the password you entered is incorrect!</p>
        </div>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Take a look at this snippet, take what you need from it. To be honest, it's not clear what you are seeking... hope it will help you understand some basics :-)

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot. I've been trying to do things for free since I'm a beginner and don't want to spend money yet, which means I have no way to use PHP to verify my passwords more securely. Unless you've got some way?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<form onSubmit="done()">
              <p>
                <input type="password" value="" placeholder="Enter Password" id="p" class="password">
                <button class="unmask" type="button" onclick="toggle()"></button>
                <button type="submit" class="enter">Enter</button>
              </p>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the function done() to be called when you hit enter you should add an event listener for Enter on your form. (Have in mind that you opened 2 form tags)

```
document.getElementById('myform-search').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if(e.key=='Enter') {
        done()
    }
}
```